# How to make IRouteConstraint filter route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wrote a custom route constraint, but its filter just doesn't get recognized.  Does anyone have an example working use of IRouteConstraint ?

Also, note to developers: I get double display of the form on my android. Something must be wrong with the partial rendering?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to set a breakpoint in your filter to see if it gets called?

Answer (score 23):

Here's a simple constraint that looks up an article slug in a fictional repository:

```
public class SlugRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly ISlugRepository slugRepository = new SlugRepository();

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out object slug))
            return false;

        return slugRepository.Exists(slug as string);
    }
}
```

You could wire up the constraint like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Slugs", "{slug}",
    new { controller = "Articles", action = "View" },
    new { slug = new SlugConstraint() });
```

Comment: Use `values.TryGetValue` so there's no double lookup