# how to do a url rewrite in asp.net with just a username

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an asp.net web application and right now users can get there profiles by putting int www.webdomain.com/page.aspx?usename=myusername. I would like to change it to www.webdomain.com/username. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "redirect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample IRouteConstraint:

```
public class IsUserActionConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    //This is a static variable that handles the list of users
    private static List<string> _users;


    //This constructor loads the list of users on the first call
    public IsUserActionConstraint()
    {
        _users= (from u in Models.Users.Get() select u.Username.ToLower()).ToList();
    }


    //Code for checking to see if the route is a username
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return _users.Contains((values["username"] as string).ToLower());
    }


}
```

And, to register the route in the Global.asax:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "User Profile", // Route name
            "{username}", 
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },//  This stuff is here for ASP.NET MVC
  new { IsUserAction = new IsUserActionConstraint() } //Your IRouteconstraint
        );
```

In my case, my user list never changes during the application life cycle so I can cache it by using a static list. I would suggest that you modify the code so that you're doing what ever check to make sure the value entered is a username inside of the Match.

Comment: I have yet to test this out because I am having trouble converting this to asp.net
new { IsUserAction = new IsUserActionConstraint() }

Comment: Post up the full code block you're using to register your route and I'll give you some help. new {} is just an anonymous object or type, in .NET 3.0 this feature was introduced. The left side is just a variable name and the right side is creating an instance of the class. Depending on where you place your class file you may have to adjust the namespace of the class, like new Path.To.Class.IsUserActionConstraint()

Comment: Using asp.net 4.0. and that parameter is expecting bool checkphysicalUrlAddress:   
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForUser", "{username}", "~/Userprofile.aspx", new IsUserActionConstraint() );

Comment: Also how is the match method ran if you never call it?

Comment: Ok i see you cant run this in asp.net, only in mvc

Answer (score 2):

Use the MVC routing. This is a good article on how to use the mvc routing with webforms:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx

Comment: Good examples. I am now able to do www.example.com/u/username. how would i get rid of the /u and just have /username, it says the reroute cannot start with /

Comment: You'll need to register a route for "{Username}" and I would suggest creating a IRouteConstraint  that would enforce the route only match when the value entered was a username. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988138/how-to-make-irouteconstraint-filter-route or  http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx

Comment: Is there anyway you can show me an example in asp.net form. I have the IRouteConstraint class but I am not sure how to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
rewriterule www.webdomain.com/.+? www.webdomain.com/page.aspx?usename=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it. You could use ASP.NET MVC and create a route using a IRouteConstraint to make sure that the username exists.

You could also create an IHttpModule that captures the Application_BeginRequest and handel request for  www.webdomain.com/username and ReWriting or TransferRequest them to www.webdomain.com/page.aspx?usename=myusername.

You could also do the code directly in the Global.asax the same way you would the IHttpModule.