# c# mvc3 controller having a overall if-statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement

im new to c# but what im trying to do instead of having a if-statement in every actionresult.

can i have a overall if-statement for the controller and just run that for every actionresult?

```
public InformationController {
if (Session["CharacterName"] == null)
{
 return RedirectToAction("logon", "Auth");
}
```

something like that?

Comment: No, conditionals like that (outside of a method body) are not valid syntax in C#. Have you looked into the Authorize attribute class and Forms Authentication? Seems like it would be easier to leverage what's already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `ActionFilterAttribute` like this:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
        //your logic here
   }
}
```

and apply this attribute to your controller

```
[MyFilter]
public class MyController : Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class by implementing IRouteConstraint for this and build up my routing with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988138/how-to-make-irouteconstraint-filter-route

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a prime candidate for an [Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx). Something like this:

```
public class CheckSessionCharacterNameAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["CharacterName"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of ASP.Net MVC framework, I prefer to implement ActionFilterAttribute class....